# How do I upload files from Django admin directly to Google Cloud Storage, and how do I render them in the templates?

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to store images in Google Cloud Storage for a production website. I have google cloud storage currently and I am wondering how to have the images uploaded in the Django admin store in GCS and how to render these in the templates.

I have tried assigning the MEDIA_URL to the GCS bucket but they are not storing. Basically I just need some guidance from the start on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to load them in Django, you can just link them.

- Make the desired bucket [publicly available](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets).
- Then, just reference the image in the template.

Finally, you can always create a Model in the DB to store the links to the images in a relational way.

Comment: Sorry my question was probably more along the lines of how to do it in a relational way. Do you know how this is achieved?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. You just call it how you normally would appending it to the end of the gcloud bucket url: https://storage.googleapis.com/[YOUR_BUCKET]/{{ model.MODELNAME}}"

Comment: Great! If you found the answer, I encourage you to post an answer!
https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this package:
https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
after you need to read this guide https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

and to provide a proper handler to you `FileField`(or `ImageField`)

If you did everything well, then the admin site should work properly.